# Int64 creating a number range

Tags: c#, sequence, number-formatting

I need to be able to creat number ranges that are 19+ digits long in sequence.

I tried using
Enumerable.Range(120000003463014,50000).ToList();

Which works for smaller numbers but using the above I get an error saying it is too big for an int32 number. Is there any way to create a sequential range with large numbers (15 digits long sometimes I would even used numbers 25 digits long). Thank you in advance

P.S. my starting number for the current issue would be
128854323463014
Ending #
128854323513013

Comment: [This](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b942f9/dealing-with-ranges-of-numbers-in-C-Sharp/) might help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create your own version that accepts `long` instead:

```
public IEnumerable<long> CreateRange(long start, long count)
{
    var limit = start + count;

    while (start < limit)
    {
        yield return start;
        start++;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var range = CreateRange(120000003463014, 50000);
```

Comment: Thank you so much nice and simple and works perfect!!

Comment: Side note... `long` is a synonym of the `Int64` type.

Answer (score 1):

Some long extensions I like to use:

```
// ***
// *** Long Extensions
// ***
public static IEnumerable<long> Range(this long start, long count) => start.RangeBy(count, 1);
public static IEnumerable<long> RangeBy(this long start, long count, long by) {
    for (; count-- > 0; start += by)
        yield return start;
}
public static IEnumerable<long> To(this long start, long finish) => start.ToBy(finish, 1);
public static IEnumerable<long> ToBy(this long start, long end, long by) {
    var absBy = Math.Abs(by);
    if (start <= end)
        for (; start <= end; start += by)
            yield return start;
    else
        for (; start >= end; start -= by)
            yield return start;
}
public static IEnumerable<long> DownTo(this long start, long finish) => start.ToBy(finish, 1);
public static IEnumerable<long> DownToBy(this long start, long min, long by) => start.ToBy(min, by);
```